# How to set Arraylist value static in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have added in `Array List<String>dynamically` get all data from web service .I need last position statically added. How to make it?

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrListViewcuisine);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

enter code here

    try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

            // JSONArray post = json;

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length()+1; ++i) {
                if(i==json.length())
                {
                    JSONObject rec1 = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    arrlistdatacuisine.add(i, rec1.getString("cuisine"));
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONObject rec1 = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrlistdatacuisine.add(i,"All Resturent");
                }


            }


            arrListViewcuisine = (ArrayList<String>) arrlistdatacuisine
                    .clone();
            Collections.sort(arrListViewcuisine);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrListViewcuisine);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

enter code here
            } catch (Exception e) {`enter code here`
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

Comment: what? im little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you asking, but what I got is you want to add something at the end of your list.

When you are adding values to the arrListViewcuisine, find the size of the arrayList and then `arrListViewcuisine.add(arrListViewcuisineSize-1,"your string");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(server result);
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i = 0; i < array.length()+1; i++) {
  if ( i==array.length()){
   mList.add(i, obj.getString("departmentname"));
 }
 else{
   obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
   mList.add(i, "add ur static value");
 }
```

}

Comment: Thank you but all data static value insert my list Give me solution

Comment: U said that u are fetching values from server and then adding these values to arraylist and after that at the end u want 1 static data to be added in the arraylist...am i getting u right???or ur problem is differebt...

Comment: Please see my code .I have followed your answer but getting all static data only

Comment: U need not to fetch value for the last item added in the arraylist.Remove the line in if condition : JSONObject rec1 = json.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: i have remove it but same problem occur

Comment: are u able to get values from rec1.getString("cuisine")..have u checked the values coming from the server???

Comment: Very very thank you it's run perfectly but small modified  i!=array.length() not = means getting result.

Comment: Please let me know List item click listener how to make call in static value string .

Comment: JSONArray array = new JSONArray(server result);
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i = 0; i < array.length()+1; i++) {
  if ( i!=array.length()){
   mList.add(i, obj.getString("departmentname"));
 }
 else{
   obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
   mList.add(i, "add ur static value");
 }

Comment: Working is fine this modified code.Thank you this coding helpful to all

Comment: i can't understand your last comment anyway how to click accept your answer?

Comment: Right side of the answer there is checkbox for accepting the answer..checked it as the right answer...

Comment: your answer below two details only there one share another one edit where it is check box?